# Is there a version of "strpart" that is aware of characters, rather than bytes

Tags: vimscript, unicode

According to `:help strpart()`, the parameters `start` and `len` are bytes, not characters, so that [image]

returns a string of 2 characters, starting with the letter *Beth*. What I'd like to have is a function, that I can pass a hebrew (or any other multibyte character string) and not have byte semantics but character semantics, so that with the parameters `2` and `4` I am returned a four character string starting with the letter *Gimmel*.

Please excuse that I am posting a picture, but when I tried to copy paste my example, the left to right/right to left handling of the stackexchange-editor got into my way.

Comment: FWIW, `:help string-functions` and `:help list-functions`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function! Strpartw(src, start, ...)
    return a:0 ?
        \ join(split(a:src, '.\zs')[a:start : (a:start + a:1 - 1)], '') :
        \ join(split(a:src, '.\zs')[a:start :], '')
endfunction
```

Comment: This seems to work, indeed. I am a bit shocked, though, that vim doesn't have an internal command to do that. I mean, it's a text editor, is it not?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger You can look at it like this: Vim runs on Commodore Amiga, BeOS, VMS, and ~10 other OSes; most of those systems don't even support multi-byte characters. ;) Or like this: the Vim project has started in 1991, basic support for UTF-8 was added in version 6, and functions dealing with wide characters have been added in version 7 (about 2010).

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger That has been discussed extensively on vim_dev. The problem is, there is no backward compatible way, so it's how it is.

Answer (score 3):

In [lh-vim-lib](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib), I'm doing it this way:

```
if exists('*strcharpart')
  function! lh#encoding#strpart(mb_string, p, l)
    " If we want a narrow contract
    " call lh#assert#value(lh#encoding#strlen(a:mb_string)).is_ge(a:p+a:l)
    return strcharpart(a:mb_string, a:p, a:l)
  endfunction
else
  function! lh#encoding#strpart(mb_string, p, l)
    " If we want a narrow contract
    " call lh#assert#value(lh#encoding#strlen(a:mb_string)).is_ge(a:p+a:l)
    return matchstr(a:mb_string, '.\{,'.a:l.'}', 0, a:p+1)
  endfunction
endif
```

The idea is that regex functions treat `.` as a character and not as a byte.

You'll also find a `strlen()` implementation and a `at()` function, but you should be able to do everything you wish with `matchstr()`.

Note that since recent Vim versions, we can use `strcharpart()`.

Comment: You should use `'.\{,'.a:l.'}'` (added comma), to make it work for `"123", 0, 5` (i.e. where the length of `mb_string` is shorter than `l`).

Comment: @blueyed. Indeed a strict compatibility with `strpart()` interface would require the function to work even when its user isn't using it properly. Personally, I prefer using narrow contracts and signalling programming errors instead of ignoring them: So far I don't see a valid scenario where I would provide a number of characters greater than length of the string.